# Animate child div after parent div has completed animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have 2 div ("a" and "b") I'm trying when div "a" slide Up and stop, div "b"
slide Up inside div "a".

```
<div id="a" class="animated slideInUp">
    <div id="b" class="animated slideInUp">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbcy09y/)

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #860169;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.animated.bounceIn,
.animated.bounceOut {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
.animated.flipOutX,
.animated.flipOutY {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}
.slideInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
  animation-name: slideInUp;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="animated slideInUp">
  <div id="b" class="animated slideInUpChild">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`translate3d(0, y%, 0)` will only translate the element in Y-axis by y% the height of the element. That is 100% would translate it by 10px (height of the child) and 10% would translate it by 1px. In addition you are positioning the element at the bottom of the parent and hence translating it by 1px (end state) is not going to have any visual effect.

You need to do the following changes to achieve the effect that you are looking for:

- Use a different animation for the child element, which will move the element from `bottom: 0px` to `bottom: calc(100% - 10px)` (the minus 10px is for the height of the element). The first keyframe at `bottom: 0px` positions the element at the bottom of the container and then gradually move it to the top of the parent element.
- Add an `animation-delay` to the child element that is equal to the `animation-duration` of parent element. This is required to make sure that the child element does not start animation before the parent element has reached the top.

**Note** that since you have `border-radius` set the to the child for the bottom-left and bottom-right, the element won't look nice once it has reached the top.

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #860169;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.animated.bounceIn,
.animated.bounceOut {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
.animated.flipOutX,
.animated.flipOutY {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}
.slideInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
  animation-name: slideInUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.slideInUpChild {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUpChild {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUpChild {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="animated slideInUp">
  <div id="b" class="animated slideInUpChild">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

---

One simple way to overcome the `border-radius` problem that I have mentioned above would be to do away with the `border-radius` and let the `overflow: hidden` setting on the parent take care of it.

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #860169;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.animated.bounceIn,
.animated.bounceOut {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
.animated.flipOutX,
.animated.flipOutY {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
  }
}
.slideInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
  animation-name: slideInUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.slideInUpChild {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  animation-name: slideInUpChild;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUpChild {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
@keyframes slideInUpChild {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="animated slideInUp">
  <div id="b" class="animated slideInUpChild">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```